# Get rowcount of large table using Entity framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I am using entity framework to get a simple rowcount of table with millions of records and I don't want any where clause.
I tried to use the Count method but it is taking very long to fetch the count. Is there any efficient way to fetch the count with waiting that long?

Comment: Do you have sample code?  If you're using the `IEnumerable` version of `Count()`, your application would be retrieving all rows and then counting them.  If you're using the `IQueryable` version of `Count()`, the database server would be doing the count and _should be fast_.

Comment: can you show your code so far ?

Comment: Just execute raw SQL query against the database. That's the probably fastest way to achieve this. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592907.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try as shown below.This query will return a `IQueryable` result.That means `count` operation happens in the database.

**Query Based :**

```
var countVal = (from a in context.yourTable
                select a).Count();
```

**Method Based :**

```
var countVal = context.yourTable.Count()
```

Comment: or simply `context.yourTable.Count()`

Comment: I found that this translates to some very poorly performing SQL, that iterates through every row in the DB:
`SELECT 
    [GroupBy1].[A1] AS [C1]
    FROM ( SELECT 
        COUNT(1) AS [A1]
        FROM [dbo].[Log] AS [Extent1]
    )  AS [GroupBy1]`  - I recommend using raw SQL, I haven't found another way.

Answer (score 5):

I think you are first retrieving all records and then count them. You should directly count your records.

```
using(DatabaseContext db = new DatabaseContext())
{
    //what I think you are doing:
    int countLong = db.UserAccount.ToList().Count();
    //what you should be doing
    int countShort = db.UserAccount.Count();
    //include where clauses inside count, wrong way:
    int countLong2 = db.UserAccount.ToList().Count(x => x.Active);
    //include where clauses inside count, good way:
    int countShort2 = db.UserAccount.Count(x => x.Active);

    //or if you don't like lambda expressions.
    int countLong3 = (from x in db.UserAccount
                      //where x.Active //optional
                      select x).ToList().Count();

    int countShort3 = (from x in db.UserAccount
                      //where x.Active //optional
                      select x).Count();

}
```

`DatabaseContext` would be your class that extends `DbContext` class